# Tablenames are missing from query in sequelize-typescript?

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I'm using sequelize-typescript on AWS lambda together with Serverless, but i'm having issues with my queries working correctly locally, but on Lamba all the table-names are empty in the SQL queries...

I have a model like this:

```
@Table
export class Manufacturer extends Model<Manufacturer> {
  @Column
  public name: string;
}
```

But the resulting query according to CloudWatch is:

```
SELECT [id], [name] FROM [s] AS [s];
```

If i run i locally it executes:

```
SELECT [id], [name] FROM [Manufacturers] AS [Manufacturer];
```

...which correctly uses the classname "Manufacturer" as the tablename... if i manually set the table-name in the @Table decorator, everything works as expected on Lambda aswell...

There is no warnings, errors or any other pointers in the logs to why this is happening...does anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the explanation myself from:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-typescript#minification
...which says:

> If you need to minify your code, you need to set tableName and
>   modelName in the DefineOptions for @Table annotation.
>   sequelize-typescript uses the class name as default name for tableName
>   and modelName. When the code is minified the class name will no longer
>   be the originally defined one (So that class User will become class b
>   for example).

I'm guessing that the Serverless does minification before shipping the code to AWS...